# How can i change property overflow?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have this code

```
import React from 'react';
import { AutoSizer, List } from 'react-virtualized';

const ListItem= () => (
<AutoSizer disableHeight>
      {({ width }) => (
        <List
          height={700}
          overscanRowCount={10}
          width={width}
          rowHeight={100}
          rowCount={publicBids.length}
          rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
          style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}
        />
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
    )
```

In the [react-virtualize docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md) say that `List` components have `Grid` component and inside have this class `ReactVirtualized__Grid and ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer`

How can i change the property `overflow` for these class ?

Comment: where you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just import a css file to declare your class to override style, like this:

```
.ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

or If your using the `styled-components`, like this:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
 .ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer {
   overflow: visible !important;
  }
`;
```

remember the element should be in Container which you want to override.